Sending two passports to VAC for Canadian Visitor Visa from USA
I have applied for Canadian visitor visa from USA for me and my wife. We completed biometrics and now received the passport request letter. I am trying to request two way courier service offered by VFS: https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/passport-submission
I have created the login and filled in my details. Its taking me to payment page without giving option to add my family member.
I am confused on how to proceed. Can someone advise.

I don't know the answer to your question. GIven how bureaucracy works, however, it is possible or even likely that VFS will want each traveler's passport in a separate shipment, thus creating a shipping reference number for each passport. Doing so would arguably provide more specific package tracking information than if multiple passports were shipped shipped in one package. Also take a look at this prior question and answer.
